# Facebook login in grails error

Tags: facebook, grails

I want to allow my users to login with facebook account. I'm using Facebook SDK for JavaScript. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

So my problem is:

When I click on the login button to login with facebook account. I get the error given below;

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

Maybe there is settings problem I guess. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks
Smac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application URL (that you are running) must match to either of the URLs in the App settings-

- `SITE URL` (if integrated with website)
- `CANVAS URL` (if canvas app)

Comment: Great! thanks for answering me. 

I have put the SITE URL but now I'm getting this error. 

**The specified feature has been temporarily disabled for this application.**

It should come back to my website again.

Comment: Sorry for late message.

Please click the below link to check error in image.

http://i42.tinypic.com/28qt0n7.png